# PowerBI - Getting a count per day from data containing date and time

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I'm fairly new to PowerBI and am having difficulty with getting a count per day form data containing both date and time. I'm using Direct Query and currently have `date_closed` and `Count of date_closed` added to the report. As you can see I presume it's counting a unique value based on the time value.

[image]

I have tried using the **Column Tools** to format to Date only hoping this would make a difference but it does not help:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way I can get a count based on just the date rather than the date **and** time?

Answer (score 1):

I would add a calculated column (e.g. **Modeling** ribbon / **New column** ) to the table, to derive the date from each date/time value. The DAX formula would be along these lines:

```
date_closed Date = DATE( YEAR( [date_closed] ) , MONTH( [date_closed] ) , DAY ( [date_closed] ) )
```

Then you can use that new column in your table to achieve the summary you want.